# DNS relay UDP on port 53

Tags: c#, sockets, dns, udp

I noticed that BT Home are sending back fake DNS results from their DNS servers and this allows sites to bypass the IP addresses i have blocked in the firewall so i was looking to create my own DNS relay/server.

So far i can receive request on UDP port 53 and send them off to the DNS server and get a valid byte[] stream result and i then send back to the browser using the remote client port the request was made on but the browser just sends the request back again.

I've tested the code from a socket and the results work OK but for some reason IE/FF simply will not except the results.

```
    public void Listen()
    {
        receiveSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp );
        receiveEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, receivePort); receiveSocket.Bind(receiveEndPoint); 
        receivePort = (receiveSocket.LocalEndPoint as IPEndPoint).Port; 
        receiveBuffer = new byte[BufferSize]; 
        receiveAsyncResult = receiveSocket.BeginReceiveFrom(receiveBuffer, 0, receiveBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref receiveEndPoint, new AsyncCallback(NetworkMessageReceivedCallback), receiveSocket);
    }


    public void NetworkMessageReceivedCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        EndPoint remoteEndPoint = null;            
        byte[] bytes = null;                        
        remoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0); //Will contain the clients port                
        int bytesRead = receiveSocket.EndReceiveFrom(asyncResult, ref remoteEndPoint);                                              
        bytes = new Byte[bytesRead];                
        Buffer.BlockCopy(receiveBuffer, 0, bytes, 0, bytesRead);
       //string ip = "208.67.222.222";
       string ip = "192.168.1.254";
       IPAddress dnsServer = IPAddress.Parse(ip);
       Response R = Resolver.Lookup(bytes, dnsServer);
       receiveSocket.SendTo(R.Message , remoteEndPoint);//127.0.0.1
       receiveSocket.Close();
       Listen();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I never dealt with raw DNS from C# but it looks like you are trying to *resolve* the bytes you received from the client, instead of just *relaying* them to the DNS server.

The message you read off the UDP socket contains a **DNS query**, not just a host name. Take a look at the [RFC 2929](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2929.txt) for what goes in there.

You might be interested in this little but great DNS filter - [adsuck](http://www.peereboom.us/adsuck/) - by Marco Peereboom (though it's for Unix, not Windows).

Answer (score 0):

Also, shouldn't your try and listen to UDP and TCP.  I think UDP is used mostly for authoritative DNS queries.

Comment: Nearly all operations are UDP. TCP is only required by AFXR, DNSSEC, and for not-so-common cases of responses larger than 512 bytes.